# How we can Copy in BQ table from another table on basis of Time or Date column?

Tags: google-bigquery

I tried this and it ran successfully but the problem is that it copied to the same table and now the rows are duplicated

Command:

```
bq cp -a 'dataset.table_name$20200501' dataset.table_name$20190301
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It seems you are appending the 20200501 partition to the 20190301 partition.  The 20200501 partition does not vanish, so those records will be in there twice (albeit under different partitions).

Answer (score 0):

If understand correctly, you are trying to copy data from one partition in one table to another partition on another table. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_cp):

The -a or --append_table flag  copy a table and append it to an existing table.

I tried the following command:

```
bq '--project_id' PROJECT_ID cp 'DATASET.TABLE1$20200703' 'DATASET.TABLE2'
```

And copied the rows from TABLE1 to TABLE2 that corresponds with the TIMESTAP after the '$'.

Check this documentation for more details: [copying partitioned table data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-table-data#copying_partitioned_table_data)

Comment: yes you are getting right but, in another Table, I'm trying to copy into another date